# How to extract some value from cookie in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx and hope to get some help.

I want to extract certain data (certain fields set by my PHP scripts) from browser cookie in nginx so that I can log it. If possible, I want to do this just by modifying nginx configuration.

Any pointer/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_cookie_

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can access cookie values by using the `$cookie_COOKIE_NAME_GOES_HERE` variable.

See [Nginx Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)

Comment: Just to save someone's time: this method only works for cookies with alphanumeric characters and '_'. If you have a cookie called user.id or user[id] (for example) you have to use $http_cookie with the nginx map function http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

Comment: @LuisClemente - any chance of a snip'it of how you would do this??

Answer (score 30):

If anyone is using the previous answer with several different cookies in the response the correct regex is:

```
map $http_cookie $auth_header {
    default "";
    "~*OAuth.AccessToken=(?<token>[^;]+)" "Bearer $token";
  }
```

or more general usage:

```
map $http_cookie $auth_header {
    default "";
    "~*yourCookieName=(?<variable>[^;]+)" "the value you wanna set $variable";
  }
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks - One tiny optimization: you don't need the `default "";` because per docs: _When default is not specified, the default resulting value will be an empty string._

Answer (score 23):

Here's an example to extract an HttpOnly cookie and pass it on to a RESTful api as an OAuth Bearer token:

```
http {

  map $http_cookie $auth_header {
    default "";
    "~*OAuth.AccessToken=(?<token>.+)" "Bearer $token";
  }

  server {
    listen                443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/certs/nginx.key;

    proxy_set_header      Authorization $auth_header;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          https://rest-api-host.domain.com/;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: For anyone using this answer, note the `[^;]` in andresbravog's answer. That's important, because the regex in this answer will only work if the OAuth.AccessToken is the last/only cookie.